# How to express floating point expressions in bash scripts

Tags: bash, floating-point

Why does

```
a2=100.    
echo 1.1*$a2|bc
```

work on the terminal, but the 3 variants in the following script don't:

```
a2=100.  
echo "  
1.1*$a2|bc  
$(1.1*$a2|bc)  
$((1.1*$a2|bc))  
">x.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't put `echo` statements in the script code piped to `x.sh`. The second variant requires an additional `echo` inside the subshell command `$(...)`. And the third variant is not valid, because `$((...))` arithmetic expansion doesn't work on floating point numbers.

```
a2=100.  
echo "  
echo 1.1*$a2|bc;  
echo $(echo 1.1*$a2|bc);
">x.sh
```

Result:

```
# sh x.sh
110.0
110.0
```